# Landmarks detection using Dlib

Tags: c++, opencv, dlib

I am currently working on a project where I have to extract the facial expression (emotions) from an images.
I'm using Dlib

in the output of `face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp`, are those the positions of the points compared to all the image or just the face ?

This is the output:

[image: Output]

Comment: You mention extracting 'emotions' - I spent a year working on this for a masters thesis, it's not quite as simple as expression == emotion. Feel free to open a chat if you want to discuss...

Comment: @LamarLatrell Hey Lamar! I'm a computer science students in the field of computer vision. Any chance you can email me at : muliastudios@gmail.com ? Thank you so much!

Comment: @LamarLatrell Thanks!

Comment: @RoiMulia, join the chat here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112826/image-processing-facial-recognition

Comment: Hey @LamarLatrell . i've requested access to the room! Thank you so much sir!

Comment: @RoiMulia, Apologies, it should have been open - it's likely you have access now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They reference pixels in the image.

i.e. 485 along and 491 down from the 0,0 in the top left corner.

You can check this yourself by drawing them, if I recall the demo does this for you (?)

They're based on the [i-bug set](http://ibug.doc.ic.ac.uk/resources/facial-point-annotations/):

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was able to extract the diffrent landmarks. Can you please tell me the next step? How can i extract the emotions ? And what is the relation between these landmarks and the Facial Action Coding System (FACS)?

Comment: @sarasara There is no extracting of emotions without an 'ethogram' - of which FACS isn't (they specifically state that). FACS is just another way to encode facial *expression* (expression != emotion). I spent a year thinking about this problem, it got quite involved, there are PHD programs in it. Which is not saying you cant get something happening under that level, it just might not be so accurate (for instance, you're only looking at static images, yet emotive information is deeply encoded in facial *dynamics* also). What sort of level are you looking at in terms of academic rigour?

Comment: i didn't really understand your question. Can you please just tell me the steps that i should follow?

Comment: Ok, ask yourself *what kind of output do you expect?*, a text output like 'happy', 'awkward stare', 'that's a bad smell!' etc... How do you define emotions in a way that would make such a system workable? Meanwhile, there is no facial landmark to emotion translator that I am aware of that works on the i-bug set. I built my own using my own marker set and it took a masters degree to get there. There have been many animation companies working in the field over the years, but their code is proprietary.

Comment: @sarasara see above ^  also, it might be better to start a chat for anyone wanting to discuss this - although, I don't see a way to open one, it may turn up if we add more comments...

Comment: i would like as an output the 7 emotions : Anger, Contempt, Fear, Disgust, Happiness, Sadness and Surprise

Comment: what i like to khnow is how to calculate the distance between the points while comparing the face with the neutral face and after that how to classifie it.

Comment: @sarasara, those emotions are a *super* low-resolution sample of our emotive space. But it can be fun to play with them. You're onto something when you mention distances, one way to go about this would be to record your face as it expresses all of those emotions and record the positions of the markers, then measure the summed distance of a *new* input face to those recorded faces... The closest 'wins'. You've got the issue of 'face-space' being different from 'image-space', so some kind of datum is required (I suggest the bridge of the nose). As for distance, google 'euclidean norm'

Comment: what do you mean by the issue of 'face-space' being different from 'image-space' ?

Comment: @sarasara, If you have the same expression when you compare them - i.e. subtract the positions from each other and sum the differences - you should get close to zero result. Now, imagine that you've got the same expression but in the top left of the frame and now in the bottom right of the frame, there will be a difference that will sum to some non-zero result here (not good). You need to account for this by removing the 'reference frame' from being image based to being based on the face.

Comment: @sarasara. In my implementation [I chose the bridge of the nose to be the zero-point origin](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RLrdq.jpg), this is a non-trivial but doable addition to your project. Either that or somehow hold the face to be in the same place perfectly every time (impossible, even with clamping helmets). Even though it is an openCV project, the same would apply for DLIB (which I initially used).

Comment: this may sound like a stupid question but can you please explain this to me. i downloaded the ck+ database and i found this file containing these values of the landmarks " 1.2345342e+02   2.2499262e+02 ... " . As you can see when i detected the points (the landmarks) i got for each point a value (x,y) (for example for the point 0 i got (485,491). So what does those values ( 1.2345342e+02) mean?

Comment: @sarasara,1.2345342e+02 means 123.45342... Which is 1.2345342*10^2.... Which is 1.2345342*100... Look up engineering notation (that's what the 'e' stands for). They are still pixels, but with *sub-pixel resolution*, i.e. floating point... Round them then cast as ints if you want them to be as you expect.

Comment: ok thank you. another question: after i got these values (x,y) do i calculate the distance or do i need to normalize the coordinates and build a matrix before (is the output of dlib already normalized)?

Comment: @sarasara, not sure what you mean by normalize in this context, and when you say 'these values', I'm not sure what values you mean. General advice, would be to simply use whatever data-sructures make it easier to 1. read/understand as you yourself think about the data and 2. code (often these result in the same data types, but not always). I'll try to put together a little psuedo-code example based on simplified smile later on today, hopefully it'll be easy to follow :)

Comment: after calculating the distance between the points for the neutral face and for the face with an expression, how do we classifiy the results?

Comment: @sarasara, You cant classify in the single case you describe, you can only get an idea of how close the expression is to neutral. The idea is to calculate the distance between the new input face and the full set of faces that exemplify each of the expressions you listed (you'll have to build this set yourself). The expression in the set that has the shortest euclidean distance to the new input face will be the 'closest' expression and it can therefore be 'classified'. But this *wont work, until the face coordinates have been extracted from the image-space*

Comment: @sarasara, Imagine a (closed) mouth defined by 3 points, left, centre and right. Imagine that the x components were set at [-1,0,1] (so we can now forget about them). Now let's define the y components for a set of expressions: neutral=[0,0,0], happy=[1,0,1], sad=[-1,0-1] (see how these make smiles and frowns?). imagine your input was [0.8, 0, 0.8] (x is the same again). Calculate the differences with the set and sum: neutral= 0.8+0+0.8=1.6, happy=0.2+0+0.2=0.4, sad=1.8+0+1.8=3.6. Sort these results, hey look! the kinda happy input was classified as happy (because it was closest/lowest :)

Comment: @sarasara.  Now, imagine if the input expression were [-1,-2,-1]. Draw this, it's a happy face ...  Now do the math again, see how 'sad' wins? It's because you *haven't dealt with face vs. image coordinates*. In this case, the central point needs to be moved up 2 places to sit where it normally would, this is what you need to manage, and I suggest using the bridge of the nose to deal with it (as it is rigid with the skull and doesn't encode any emotive/expressive information)

Comment: ok. this is how i calculated the distance for the neutral face and the face with expressions :

Comment: // the distance between the eyebrows to detect the anger

    dist1 = distanceCalculate(shape.part(21).x(), shape.part(21).y(), shape.part(22).x(), shape.part(22).x());

Comment: // the distance between the bridge and the tip of the nose to detect the disgust

double dist2 = distanceCalculate(shape.part(27).x(), shape.part(27).y(),shape.part(30).x(), shape.part(30).y());

Comment: // the distance between the tips of the mouth to detect a smile

double dist3 = distanceCalculate(shape.part(48).x(), shape.part(48).y(),shape.part(54).x(), shape.part(54).y());

Comment: first is there any mistakes ? and how can i define the emotions based on these distances?
( i'm i suppose to calculate the distance between diffrent points or the distance for each point in the neutral face and the face with expression)
should i use a learning algorithm like SVM for the classification? and how ?

Comment: @sarasara Mistakes, likely yes as you've simplified the model too much, but I can't tell what you're doing in distanceCalculate anyway so... SVM, why?? Now you're adding unnecessary complexity. I've already explained how it's done, please go back and read what I've tried again, Google the terms you do not understand. Especially relevant is 'Euclidean norm', also read up about the concept of 'nearest neighbor'. What level of education are you in? Have you done any linear algebra? (I can explain things faster if you have).

Comment: i've calculated the distance like this: distance = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2); As for my education, i'm doing my final year project ( computer engineering master). shouldn't i use a learning algorithms for the classification like SVM, K-Neighbors..?

Comment: @sarasara, please find a way for us to continue this discussion outside of these comments ...  Meanwhile, did you follow my example with the smile from above (11 comments or so ago)? In one comment I describe how the system works without any fancy machine learning classifiers :). Please do this example on paper and see how it works. But again, we cant keep communicating this way, *why hasn't the chat link popped up???*

Comment: @sarasara, ok you need 20rep to be able to use the chat rooms ...  try to ask some good questions on this site (pertaining to your project), if they're written well and show some research I'll upvote you past 20rep *and* hopefully answer your questions :). Meanwhile, you could also 'accept' my answer (the little green tick by my answer), that'l help my rep too ...

Comment: ok thank you i will try to review your example. in the example do you have to define in the begining what are the (x,y) for happy and sad?

Comment: @sarasara, Yes, in the example happy, neutral and sad are defined beforehand. The x positions stay the same for all expressions, that's why I don't use x,y pairs (x is redundant). The idea is that you simply compare new input (using euclidean differences) to these expressions and find the closest. Closest wins ... job done ! If you were using a ML technique then in training it you'd be defining the training set 'in the beginning' also. Once again, I need to state that it'll only work once you figure out how to use facial-relative positions and not absolute (image-based) marker positions.

Comment: so i should bring all the facial landmarks at the same point of origin on a landmark ( and use the bridge of the nose to be the zero-point origin). how can i do that?

Comment: @sarasara. In every case just subtract point28 from all points. Then you will have gone from an image based absolute reference, to a local face based relative reference (relatice to the point28 zero/datum). You'll end up with negative positions for the top left facial quadrant, but the math will be fine...

Comment: this example is just for the emotions : happy and sad what if we want to add the other emotions (Anger,Fear, Disgust and Surprise)?

Comment: @sarasara. Well, you add them yourself! Build up a set of expressions by recording your face (to file or whatever) as you make those expressions. Mine had 48, it wasn't enough for my purposes, but it allowed me to see the system failing, which was interesting. The more you put in there, the better it is. You could use an SVM/ANN if you like, but you're going to have to do a *lot* of training, which amounts to the same procedure of recording expressions (but many times over). How far are you through your project? I would have thought you're going to have to do more than this right?

Comment: @LamarLatrell Hello, Lamar. Can you check [my question about landmarks detection and training shape predictor in dlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880441/low-accuracy-of-shape-predictor-with-default-dataset-and-training). I tried to ask this question on the dlib's sourceforge but nobody answered me.

Comment: On some case I saw DLIB can generate the Eyebrow contour. How can one do that?

Comment: @Royi, points 18 through 27 are effectively the eyebrows, use them.  (?)

Comment: @LamarLatrell I need the contour. I saw one can get it using the 194 points model. I wonder if someone had done it.

Comment: Use standard contour processes? Not sure why you are asking this here.